# Adding backtick to column name when building mysql query from a string

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building up my SQL queries from a database handler class. But, I'm having trouble adding the backtick's around the column name. I need the backtick's because the table have a column named ADMIN and my query fails because its a reserved keyword in the mysql version I'm using.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'ADMIN LIKE
>   '%search_string%' OR BAN LIKE '%search_string%')  ORDER BY ID DESC'

Very simplified underneath is a description on how i use the class

I send in the $where clause to the class like this

```
$where = array("ID" => "%search_string%", 
               "USERNAME"=> "%search_string%", 
               "ADMIN"=> "%search_string%", 
               "BAN" => "%search_string%");
```

Then to add placeholders for the prepared statement

```
$where = implode(" LIKE ? $andOr ", array_keys($where));
```

And get "ID LIKE ? OR USERNAME LIKE ? OR ADMIN LIKE ? OR BAN LIKE ?"

I have tried adding a foreach loop to change the column names like this

```
foreach($where as $key => $value) {
    $where["`" . $key "`"] = $value;
    unset($where[$key]);
}
```

But that do not work as I then get the column name as a string in the query like this `` "'`ID`' LIKE ? OR '`USERNAME`' LIKE ? OR '`ADMIN`' LIKE ? OR '`BAN`' LIKE ?" `` and mysql gives me an error about `` "`column_name`" `` do not exist

Is there anyway to add the backtick's to the column name when dealing with strings like this or will I have to rename the column name ADMIN and go through the whole page and change the script with the new column name?

Comment: Your database class is badly written. It should auto-add these backsticks.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do now tho.

Comment: Do you have this problem using an alias? If you add `your_alias.column_name` does `admin` still a problem?

Comment: that fixes the problem Mickael. So if there's no way of adding backticks in a string ill use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use array map to automatically  add backticks to the columns as you input them into the implode function.

```
$where = implode(" LIKE ? $andOr ", 
    array_map(function($key) {
        return "`$key`";
    }, array_keys($where))
);
```